# Office ui fabric react not working with SharePoint hosted app!

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, visual-studio, spfx, spfx-webparts

I have created SharePoint hosted app using VS2015, and in that i have used Office ui fabric react components. I have installed it and other packages of React and React-dom using npm, App is successfully deployed on my developer site. But fabric css is not rendering on my react components. If i explicitly give link to fabric.css like

```
> <link  href="../node_modules/office-ui-fabric-react/dist/css/fabric.min.css"rel="stylesheet" />
```

on my default.aspx, it works. I want to ask that is there any way, may be, some configuration file where i just specify  this

```
{
  ...
  css : 'node_modules/office-ui-fabric-react'
  ...
}
```

to render css on page. If i use same procedure with my SharePoint framework app css renders without any issue.  Any help ??